# Force Close Error in a very simple Android code

Tags: android

my *.java :

```
package com.google.multiplier;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Multiplier extends Activity {
    private EditText num1,num2,res;
    private int result;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_multiplier);
        num1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
        num2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText2);
        res=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        result=(Integer.parseInt(num1.getText().toString()))*(Integer.parseInt(num2.getText().toString()));


        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    res.setText(Integer.toString(result));

                }
            });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_multiplier, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

and the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="126dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/EditText1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/EditText1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/EditText1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/EditText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/bt" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you may see it is a simple multiplier. I launch it in an Android 4.0 emulator and it get force close error but the compiler did not find any error before running. How can I find where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your calculation to button click implementation

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    result=(Integer.parseInt(num1.getText().toString()))*(Integer.parseInt(num2.getText().toString()));

    res.setText(Integer.toString(result));

}
```

Right now, what is happening is in onCreate method, while it is trying to create your activity, at the calculation it checks `num1.getText().toString()` which is `""`. On doing, 
`Integer.parseInt("")`, the complier getting confused.
You said that you are not getting any kind of exception. Surprisingly, I am getting a `NumberFormatException` on my end when using your code.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.parseInt` will fail if given an empty string (such as when your activity is first created). You should instead compute `result` in your `OnClickListener`.